# How can I connect my auto-created account to a newly created one?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I wasn't sure what wording to choose when searching, so this may have been asked before. After [a question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/ui-repetitive-code-what-pattern-to-use) on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) was asked, and I answered it, the question was moved to [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). In the past, I remember that accounts were auto-created, but this doesn't seem the case any longer, as my name under the question is grey.

I wondered whether when I create a new account on CR, I could connect that to these existing answers, if possible. I already have an [SE](http://stackexchange.com) account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new account on CR that's associated with your Stack Overflow account, you'll automatically take ownership of your migrated answer.

Basically, just make a new account on CR and use one of your existing OpenID log-ins.

Comment: True, this will also give you +100 rep in the new account to have a good starting point. (As far as I know this requires you to have at least one account with over 200 rep in one of the other sites, to prove  you're worthy - in the OP case it holds true)

Comment: Worked like a charm, I could've just tried it to find that one out. Thanks!